# Entitymaanger between tests

Tags: jboss-arquillian

I have 2 Arquillian test's both that work independently of one another, but when I package them together for deployment the build fails. I am pretty new to arquillian so forgive me if this is an easy solution, but I was wondering if there is a way that you are supposed to handle an Entitymanager between tests. I concluded that the error with the build might be coming from the entity manager since I declare one in both test classes. Any ideas?

I believe this is the error that is in question:
`org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001409 Ambiguous dependencies for type [EntityManager] wi
th qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject @RequestScoped protected com.ferguson.sb.dao.Gen
ericDAO.em]. Possible dependencies [[Resource Producer Field [EntityManager] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]
declared as [[field] @PersistenceContext @Produces com.ferguson.sb.dao.UserDAOTestARQ.em], Resource Producer
Field [EntityManager] with qualifiers [@Any @Default] declared as [[field] @PersistenceContext @Produces stat
ic com.ferguson.sb.dao.BdgbranchInfoDaoTestARQ.em]]]`

Comment: It might help if you post what error you're receiving.

Comment: You should have a single producer for the entity manager, or else just inject it as `@PersistenceContext`